# When I mine a rock in my game (Click it 10 times) it mines and gives 100 coins. However if someone else does it it gives it to me? Can anyone h3lp?

Tags: roblox, luau

So when I click it 10 times it mines however it only give coins to me when someone else mines it. I have no clue really what to do so i need help. Ok so here is the script:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

    script.Parent:Clone()

    local money = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats").Money

    script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
        local billboard = script.Parent.BillboardGui
        print(health)
        health = health - 1
        billboard.Enabled = true
        billboard.TextLabel.Text = health
        if health == 0 then
            local clickdetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
            billboard.Enabled = false
            money.Value = money.Value + 100
            script.Parent.ClickDetector.Parent = nil
            script.Parent.Union.Transparency = 1
            script.Parent.Union.CanCollide = false
            wait(5)
            clickdetector.Parent = script.Parent
            script.Parent.Union.Transparency = 0
            script.Parent.Union.CanCollide = true
            health = 10
        end
    end)
end)
```

Comment: If you test this with multiple players, is it giving money to every player?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to make sure the `player` variable matches the player that clicked it.

```
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
```

should be:
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(clicker)

and use an if statement:

```
if clicker == player then
    --code that gives points
end
```

Also when you clone the parent it clones the script so that may cause bugs.